# How to show latest content in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My Question table has the following columns: id, question, answer, created_at, updated_at, sender_id, recipient_id.

The latest questions should appear on top.

Questions Controller:

```
 def index
    @questions = Question.all
    respond_with(@questions)
end

def show
  @question = Question.find(params[:id])
  respond_with(@questions)
end
```

Answers Controller:

```
  def new
    @question = Question.find(params[:question_id])
  end

  def create
    @question = Question.find(params[:question_id])
    if @question.update_attributes(params[:question])
      redirect_to questions_path
    else
      render :new
    end
```

Routes:

```
  resources :questions do
    resources :answers, only: [:new, :create]
  end
```

Comment: When you say "the latest questions should appear on top", on which attribute do you want your order on? Created at? Updated at?

Comment: It would be created_at

Comment: Then @Miotsu posted a correct answer for your needs ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@questions = Question.order("created_at DESC")
```